# Headings not working in my R markdown file

Tags: r, r-markdown, xquartz

I recently finished my R notebook, and noticed something once I decided to knit the markdown file. None of the headings or bullet points were working! I had to install XQuartz to finish knitting the markdown file since I have a mac. Is this something that's normal or can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding a space after the `#`s?

Comment: Yeah thats what worked! Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't seen your rmarkdown, but I suspect that you need to add a blank line above each heading. For example, putting a heading right after a list (or any other structure) sometimes results in problems:

```
1. First item
2. Second item
3. Third item
# First level heading
```

However, adding a blank line before each heading usually fixes the problem:

```
1. First item
2. Second item
3. Third item

# First level heading
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to figure it out just needed a space after the hashtag

Answer (score 0):

Your headings do not work because you didn't leave a space between "#" and the next character.

This will not work:

```
##Main Questions
```

Instead, do this:

```
## Main Questions
```